# Use progress bar as tracker in extjs

Tags: extjs4, progress-bar, sencha-architect

I would like to know if we can use the progress bar in extjs 4.2 as a tracker. I want to customize the progress bar so that it gets updated based on an event. Also, when it gets updated or progresses, a new message regarding the event occurred should appear on it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://try.sencha.com/extjs/4.1.1/docs/Ext.ProgressBar.1/

Should work with 4.2 as well.